# can anyone please provide some script of statement for automating Siebel Open UI application usig UFT with Siebel open UI Add-in Enabled

Tags: qtp, siebel

Has anybody tried for Automating Siebel open UI application using UFT  if yes , please let me know how would be the scripts looks like ??? . I have the Siebel open UI Add-in Enabled however still it is identifying as Web object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siebel Open UI is implemented as a [WebExtensibility](http://www.advancedqtp.com/DemoMTW/content/tech.web_ext.html) project in UFT so most of the objects will still be recognised as plain web-objects. The two main differences that Siebel Open UI support adds are:

1. New test objects are added, the most common of which is `SblOUIAdvancedEdit`.
2. Additional levels are added into the object repository in order to segment the application more correctly, these objects are usually `SblOUIApplet` but `SblOUITable` will also contain the objects within it.

So a typical script line could look something like:

```
 Browser("B").Page("P").SblOUIApplet("Orders").WebButton("create").Click
```

Regarding `SblOUIAdvancedEdit` this object is not identified for every edit field, only those which have an *opener* element inside it which allows opening a dialog to set the edit field (see picture below).

[image: WebEdit vs SblOUIAdvancedEdit]

Comment: Thanks for the resolution. I have worked for Siebel HI (High Interactive )application earlier and  followed the same steps as provided by you. But want to ask you whether this STA enabled and  SiebelAx_TestAutomation_.exe  will work for Siebel Open UI application as well. Please reply..  If yes then I will follow the same approach.

Comment: @RohitArora, ooops I misread the question, sorry :( Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir..  This is very helpful information if you have some  more information related to this please share with me.  I was getting this kind of script only for  SbOUITree however  I did not get  the text box as SblOUIAdvancedEdit as you have mentioned instead it is identifying as WebEdit object.  Can it be happen that text box would be developed using Web (HTML ) technology means no interference of Siebel Open UI mens Jss Script.  Please reply if you have some  inputs on the above scenario.

Comment: Huge thanks for the this relevant information. Appreciate your valuable response.  do we need to enable others add-in as well (like : java , Siebel or Oracle ) along with Siebel open UI Add-In while scripting for open UI and do we require  STA Enabled for Open UI as well or it will work without these configuration.

Comment: @RohitArora, you only need Web + SiebelOUI, there's no need for STA to be enabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Now I have confidence to start with open UI Automation. Nice to have knowledge share with you. In future as well will come to  you for any kind of trouble :) :)